# Is there a way to make MongoDB Atlas Cloud DB work like a Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, node.js, mongodb-atlas

I am making an **Android Java Application** which requires following features;

**Required Features for the Application**

- Messaging between 2 users or multiple users that include;
- Text messaging, Voice messaging, image messaging(Just like WhatsApp)
- Push Notifications whenever a user gets a message, or someone takes a screenshot in chat (Just like Snapchat)
- In App Voice calls and Video calls

**Technology Stack**

- **Java** for Android in Android Studio
- **NodeJS** for making API
- **MongoDB Atlas Cloud Client** for Database

**What I did**
I was making the API Get request to Get all the messages from the Database and display it on the RecyclerView but since the Database is not Realtime so whenever a new message is added in Database then I would have to open the application again from scratch so that a new Get request is sent and the data is fetched to RecyclerView.

**Question**
Hence,

1. Is there a way to make chatting Realtime with the mentioned technology stack? That is; with NodeJS and MongoDB Atlas Client without having to **buy the realtime database**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using their new feature that's called mongodb realm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).